# How to change property of a record in db with cypress.io

Tags: node.js, database, cypress

I'm new to cypress and I'm wondering how can I do the following checks:
I have a case:
I have a product in the DB, that can have statuses: InStock and OutOfStock and Discontinued. If a product is in 'InStock ' status, I should be able to dispatch it to a customer, if in 'OutOfStock'/ 'Discontinued' i should not be able to dispatch to a customer.
With an API call I can dispatch the product to a customer. If a product is in 'InStock' status, the API response is 200, if not the response is with statusCode 400.
So my question is: How can I change the status of the product in the DB for each test, so I can check each of the 3 statuses (if the API returns the proper response)? I know how to check the API response itself, but it's not clear to me how to change the status of the product in the DB, before each test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike @Maccurt, I *would* actually do it the way you propose (change the DB), so you can properly test e2e flow.

And instead of setting up test routes which would write to the DB you can use  [`cy.task`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Syntax) to talk to the Cypress Runner's node process which can write to the DB directly. It'd look like this:

Using postgres ([node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres)) in this example.

`your-test.spec.js`

```
describe("test", () => {
    it("test", () => {
        cy.task("query", {
            sql: `
                UPDATE product
                SET status = $1
                WHERE id = $2
            `,
            values: [ "InStock", 40 ]
        });

        // your cy assertions here
    });
});
```

`cypress/plugins/index.js`

```
const pg = require("pg");
const pool = /* initialize your database connection */;

module.exports = (on) => {
    on("task", {
        query ({ sql, values }) {                
            return pool.query(sql, values);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I find all this interesting. I am confused as to what we are testing here. If we are testing the API and the Database then I would say this test should not be a Cypress test. Let me look harder to see what we are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: [Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Don%E2%80%99t-Stub-Responses) themselves note that there's value in e2e. Having separate DB/endpoint tests (or stubbing cypress tests) is useful (we're doing it too), but doesn't give you 100% guarantee your web app is gonna work as expected.

Comment: Your suggestion @Dwelle is exactly what i was looking for i think. In my case i want to connect to mysql db, but when i follow your idea, i'm stuck with the following error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Not sure where you're getting the error, but likely from the `query` task which tries to JSON stringify the return value of your db query. If so, you should do something like `return pool.query(sql, values).then( resp => resp.rows )` or whatever applies to you. If it's not that, then other candidate is when you call the `cy.task('query', data)` - ensure the `data` you pass is a plain object with no circular references to itself.

Comment: Here is the index.js:
`const pool = mysql.createPool(config)

module.exports = ( on ) => { 
    on('task', {
        querydb (statement) {
            return pool.query(statement)
        }
    })
}`

and the test itself:
`describe("test", () => {
    it("test", () => {
        cy.task('querydb', 'UPDATE table SET status = 0 WHERE product = 5035;');
    });
});`
Still getting the error: `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`
also tried using `return pool.query(statement).then( resp => resp.rows )`, but then i get:`TypeError: pool.query(...).then is not a function`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the mysql node driver you're using, but it seems that it doesn't return a promise - thus (if it's callback-based), you should do something like: `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => pool.query(statement, (err, data) => { if ( err ) return reject(err); resolve(data); }))`

Answer (score 0):

You want to mock your api call so it responds with what you want.  Cypress calls it stubbing. This will allow you to intercept your Rest call and replace it with what you want. You could also call an API to reset your DB, but I would not recommend that.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Requests

```
cy.server()           // enable response stubbing
cy.route({
  method: 'GET',      // Route all GET requests
  url: '/users/*',    // that have a URL that matches '/users/*'
  response: []        // and force the response to be: []
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Maccurt, but what i want to check is if the api response is the proper one, when there are strict circumstances in the database. That has nothing to do with the request or the response (i cannot control the state of the product). Basically in the request i give the id of the product and request to dispatch it, then in the response i expect 400 - if the product is not in the proper state, or 200 if all is good and it is dispatched.

Comment: If you are trying to test the API and the DB, could you put that test in that layer?

Comment: I want to test the API only. The problem is that i can assert the api response is as expected only if i know the status of the product in the db. Also i have to check the api response against different product statuses and the easiest way i could think of was to change those statuses myself in the db with update query.