# cleaning up back-end data in Salesforce between Cypress tests using JSforce

Tags: salesforce, cypress, jsforce

I'm using the [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) testing framework to test a web application which has a Salesforce back-end.

I'm looking for a way to **ensure that all data is cleaned up (deleted) from the Salesforce back-end after (or before) each test is run**. My purpose is to make sure that all tests can be run independently and in any order, and to make sure that the back-end data gets cleaned up (deleted) even in the event of a failing test.

Unless you have any suggestions on a better way of implementing this, I'm thinking that the best approach is to use [JSforce](https://jsforce.github.io/) to perform the data clean up from within the Cypress test file.

Comment: As of now your question might be flagged as unclear. Please explain in details what do you mean by *cleaning up the back-end*.

Comment: @Nino Filiu It means deleting any data on the back-end in between tests to make sure each test can execute from a consistent starting point. I have added more language to my question to clarify. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cy.task`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Syntax#article) for this:

**cypress/support/index.js:**

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.task('cleanUp');
});
```

**cypress/plugins/index.js:**

```
module.exports = ( on ) => {
    on('task', {
        cleanUp () {
            // do your thing with your back-end
        }
    });
};
```

For more, see [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54448286/927631).